# Aggregator vs Parent in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have Multi-modules project, and I'm trying to switch into Maven from Ant. It's not clear when can I use the aggregator or parent pom.

The structure of the project looks like the following:

```
root
    • Web app
        ○ child-1
        ○ child-2
        ○ Monitoring Server
        ○ Adapter
    • Adapter
        ○ child-1
        ○ child-2
    • Monitoring Server
        ○ child-1
        ○ child-2
```

When can I use the aggregator, and which method should be used for the above structure?

Comment: Do all those project belong together ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah, they are all in the same directory and belong together (structure graph has been updated). As can be seen, one of the modules (Web App) depend on the other 2 modules

Comment: Then I would suggest to really make a root parent pom in your directory `root` which contains the definition of plugins versions and the list of modules `Web app`, `Adapter` and `Monitoring Server` (I would suggest to make lowercase directory names without any space in it). Also a dependency managet of all dependencies you would like to use in your modules.... in the `Web app` directory put also a pom file which contains a list of modules `child-1`, `child-2`, `Monitoring server` and `adapter`... and so on ... so you can define simply dependencies between the modules you need that's it...